# how to index columns for case-insensitive search using Hibernate Criteria on different databases

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, indexing

I am using hibernate and have already in place a search by criteria that is case-insensitive. However the search ***performance*** is lacking. I do not know how to set up the configuration so that is works on Oracle as well as on Sql-Server. Because

- case-insensitive columns are only supported by Sql-Server
- function based indexes are only supported by Oracle

There is the option of creating a new column for case-insensitive search, but then I would have to adjust all my bindings or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are searching for is "collation".

Usually collation is specified at the database, column or query level, and possibly also at index level.

I don't think there is an implementation of specifying collation at query level in Hibernate.

You might use [native queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) where you might be able to use database specific functions like [COLLATE in SQLServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) or [COLLATE in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/COLLATE-Operator.htm#SQLRF-GUID-1B8CE3B0-77FC-455C-8400-6F81CF188D7B) to cast the collation for a given expression.